# display:none when no related items. opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: php, css, opencart

I work with opencart 1.5.6.4,the journal2 theme and I have made a custom related item on the product page. Only for some products I don't have any related items and I would like to disable the display of it.

Screendump of result:

[image: Screendump of result]

Would anybody have a suggestion on how to do so?

My code as xml vqmod:

```
<modification>
    <id>Related Products Custom tab </id>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <vqmver>2.1.5</vqmver>
    <author>13Pixels</author>
    <file name="catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/product/product.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[<div class="related-custom-spot">]]>
            </search>
        <add><![CDATA[
<div class="related-custom" style="background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);">
    <?php if ($heading_title): ?>
    <div class="secondary-title" style="background-color: rgb(169, 184, 192); margin: 0px;"><?php echo $tab_related; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="related-custom-pictures">
            <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                 <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">
                            <img style="border-width: 5px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);" width="50px" height="50px" src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
                        </a>

                   <?php } ?>         
                <?php } ?>
           </div> 
     </div>
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below condition, before displaying related items

```
<?php  if ($products)  { ?>
//your code to display related items
<?php } ?>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks mate!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to sort the images? for example; sort order table in the product table? Then it would be perfect, see: https://www.rijstextiles.com/net-stof-stretch-mesh/mesh-stof-stretch-zwart.html

Comment: <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>